# How to select value in cloned select menu list - JQuery Mobile

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using "Add/remove fields dynamically" script Based on the great post by Charlie Griefe. However when I try to clone a select menu jQuery Mobile only allows me to select the value in the static select menu.

The Script to clone my select menu

```
<script>


$(document).ready(function() {


    $('#btnAdd').click( function() {

        $('#btnDel').removeAttr('disabled').button('enable'); // enable the "del" button

        // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
        var num = $('.clonedInput').length; 

        // the numeric ID of the new input field being added  
        var newNum  = new Number(num + 1);    
        var newElem = $('#input' + num ).clone().attr('id', 'input' + newNum);

        newElem.children(':first').attr( 'id', 'name' + newNum ).attr('name', 'name_label[]');
        $('#input' + num).after(newElem);


        // business rule: limit the number of fields to 5
        if (newNum == 5) {
             $('#btnAdd' ).attr('disabled', 'disabled').button('disable');
             $('#btnAdd').parent().find('.ui-btn-text').text('maximum fields reached');
        }                        
    });

    $( '#btnDel' ).click( function() {
        // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have           
        var num = $( '.clonedInput' ).length; 

        // remove the last element  
        $('#input' + num ).remove();

        // enable the "add" button, since we've removed one       
        $('#btnAdd').removeAttr('disabled').button('enable'); 
        $('#btnAdd').parent().find('.ui-btn-text').text('add another name');

        // if only one element remains, disable the "remove" button
        if ( num-1 == 1 )
        $('#btnDel' ).attr('disabled', 'disabled').button('disable');

    });  

});           
</script>
```

The select menu:

```
div id="input1" class="clonedInput" style="margin-bottom: 4px;"> 
              <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                   <label for="item_ordered">Ordered Item:</label>
                      <?php
                      $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'retail_management_db') 
                                          or die ('Cannot connect to db');
                    $result = $conn->query("SELECT item_Id,itemName FROM CompanyInventory");

                    echo '<select name="itm_order" value="'.escape(Input::get('itm_order')).'"><option>Select Item</option>';
                         while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                            unset($id, $name);
                            $id = $row['item_Id'];
                            $name = $row['itemName']; 
                            echo '<option value="'.$name.'">'.$name.'</option>';
                          }
                    echo '</select>';
                      ?>

                   </div>      
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">

                      <label for="item_ordered">Units:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity" value="<?php  echo escape(Input::get('quantity')); ?>">

                 </div> 
              </div>      
          <div>
              <input id="btnAdd" type="button" value="Add another item" data-inline="true">
              <input id="btnDel" type="button" value="Remove item" disabled="disabled" data-inline="true">
          </div>
```

I'm also adding values from my database dynamically into the select menu.

Comment: I've also attempted it just using the jQuery mobile select menu form widget, instead display it using php dynamically.